# Adobe CQ 5 Accepts Arbitrary POST Request

Tags: aem, iis-8, sling

i know that Adobe CQ 5 was built on top of Apache Sling (which using JackRabbit). I'm a bit baffled as for why the website will accept arbitrary POST request from outside (unauthenticated user) into Publish Instance through the Dispatcher and then reply with HTTP 200 Content Updated. Should not content update only allowed from Author Instance in this case? Should not such request met with HTTP 403 response instead? - Why is it that even not logged in can get HTTP Response 200?

The response looked like this:

```
    {
        "changes": [],
        "referer": "http://www.example.com/content/somesite/en.html",
        "path": "/content/somesite/en",
        "location": "/content/somesite/en",
        "parentLocation": "/content/somesite",
        "status.code": 200,
        "status.message": "OK",
        "title": "Content modified /content/somesite/en"
    }
```

I've set POST Referrer Filter for now to prevent arbitrary POST request 'outside' the website got accepted, however i can still get this response by typing jquery ajax request in the browser console while opening the website.
I do wonder if this is bad or something, really new to Adobe CQ.

The JQuery Script for testing it is actually only these:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/content/fasfas',
    type: 'post',
    data: {},
    headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anonymous and everyone should not have post permissions on arbitrary paths which is the default cause on publisher run mode. Are you sure this is configured correctly? Which version and SP are you using exactly?

Comment: Just a side-note: Apache Sling *is not* an implementation of Jackrabbit. Jackrabbit is a JCR implementation and it's used by Apache Sling as a repository.

Comment: @i.net i'm using Adobe CQ 5.6 10.0.10.167. i do wonder why, since Anonymous did not have any write permission in the user management page..

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue of not taking the necessary steps to secure the AEM servers. There is a [security checklist](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/administer/security/security-checklist.html) provided by Adobe to ensure that AEM installation is secure when deployed. Similar [security checklist for the dispatcher](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/security-checklist.html) is also present.

As for your case, there are few issues which are evident

1. The filter configuration within the dispatcher doesn't deny POST
   requests, thereby allowing them to pass through the dispatcher and reach the AEM instance.
2. The anonymous user in the AEM publisher seems to have more than just
   READ privileges on the repository thereby allowing him to make changes to the repo using POST requests.
3. The referrer filter configuration was allowing requests from external systems as well (which you have blocked now).

Comment: could you pointed out which part of the security checklist regarding this post issue? i've spent some time fiddling on OSGi Bundle Configuration.. and found nothing yet.. although i'm interested on the fact that anon can do more than read, does ACL did not replicated? previous developer said that he already applied all of [security checklist for CQ 5](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/deploying/security_checklist.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your dispatcher should block all POST operations on the publisher. This is recommended in [Adobe's official documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/dispatcher/disp-config.html) for configuring dispatcher.

Publisher should also disable write permission for anonymous users and everyone group to paths that are not allowed to be modified by community. Unless you are using CUG, write should be disabled for anonymous across the publisher instance.

Comment: i see, so its best to block or POST request rather than finding out the reason of anonymous user can get 200 instead 403.. anyway if i apply this blockage through IIS is there any differences? will publish become unable to flush dispatcher cache?

Comment: By default sling POST handler servlet creates a node on the URI path. As long as the user has write permissions and there are no constraints for the node types on the parent path the servlet will return a HTTP 200 response as expected. You should block POST via your dispatcher (or IIS) and also revoke write permission of anonymous users. Dispatcher flush is not controlled by POST permissions and you normally configure a different higher privileged user account for dispatcher flush rather than using anonymous user account.

Comment: i see, regarding the permission, anonymous users only allowed to read. but it still baffles me that it got 200 http ok response.

Comment: Does this happen directly on publisher? if you post without going through the dispatcher, do you still get 200 response?

Comment: Well check the path in your authentication handler and also check effective permissions on the node where post is allowed via crxde